# how do I troubleshoot fatal errors for simple commands: recursive gc invocation error after library()

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm getting an error for "recursive gc invocation" just loading some packages. If I set my code to run further, this error continues to pop out throughout, and R studio experiences a fatal error and aborts. I do not know how to trouble shoot this to fix it.

I have already tried to restart the program, but get the same error in the same place. This happens even if I restart the program, close the project, and try again in a new / blank script. The error is shown below.

What are appropriate steps at this juncture? Should I uninstall /reinstall R? Is there a better way to try to pinpoint what is going wrong?

This is what I get in the console when I load these two libraries:

```
> library(descr)
> library(data.table)
*** recursive gc invocation
*** recursive gc invocation
*** recursive gc invocation
data.table 1.14.2 using 4 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
```

I included session info if that helps, but honestly I'm not really sure where to begin trouble shooting this.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] beepr_1.3         nngeo_0.4.4       stringr_1.4.0     bit64_4.0.5       bit_4.0.4         sf_1.0-5          data.table_1.14.2 descr_1.1.5      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7         magrittr_2.0.1     units_0.7-2        xtable_1.8-4       R6_2.5.1           rlang_0.4.12       tools_4.1.2        grid_4.1.2        
 [9] audio_0.1-10       KernSmooth_2.23-20 e1071_1.7-9        DBI_1.1.2          ellipsis_0.3.2     class_7.3-19       lifecycle_1.0.1    vctrs_0.3.8       
[17] glue_1.6.0         stringi_1.7.6      proxy_0.4-26       compiler_4.1.2     generics_0.1.1     classInt_0.4-3
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "some packages"? Does it always happen when you load `descr` then `data.table`? Or only sometimes? Does it happen with other packages? What if you load them in a different order? Is this a brand new install of R? Do you have a personal Rprofile or Renviron file that loads when you start R? You've listed your R version, but what RStudio version are you using as well?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Running R 4.1.2 and RStudio 2021.09.2+382 "Ghost Orchid"  for Windows.

Comment: I've tried a couple of packages, and it happens irrespective of what I load. I assume if Rui cannot repeat it, then it's an error locally. If it's happening will all packages should I uninstall and reinstall R or are there other steps that I should take first?

Comment: This is a great question I'm happy to follow, hang in there! I have one (long) script that crashes R(studio) more or less randomly with the same "recursive gc invocation", possibly also in the context of loading packages. Due to the randomness I have a hard time to reproduce the issue. Weirdly enough, after a few crashes it works fine. There is hardly anything to find about it on the internet.

Comment: E.g. `*** recursive gc invocation *** recursive gc invocation*** recursive gc invocation Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’ in .getGenericFromCacheTable(name, where, pkg, .genericTable):
 'rho' must be an environment not pairlist: detected in C-level applyClosure`. R 4.1.2, RStudio 2021.09.0/351, Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To others who may find this problem, this is what I did. I don't know how it fixed it, but it's working;

1. I ran into the problem, restarted R and retried: same problem
2. I opened a new project / blank script, copied the code and tried the code again: same problem
3. I tried it with slightly different code: same problem
4. I restarted my computer and tried steps 1:3 again: same problem
5. I uninstalled and resintalled R: solved.

Is this a good way to solve this problem? No clue. Will this work for everyone? Also no idea. But it fixed it in my case.  ¯_(ツ)*/¯ ¯_(ツ)*/¯

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem.
Loading data.table and then having those recursive gc invocation.
I have found it to be very close in nature to this issue:
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10565

no fixes yet, but seems to be an Rstudio Ghost Orchid issue

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. My solution below.

I ran into this after

- my computer (MacBook Pro 2017 running on OSX Big Sur 11.2.1) crashed (I don't know the reason)
- when I re-opened an R project where "big data" had been loaded into the environment, it froze (I assume it struggled to find / load the data) and no matter what I tried (restart R, clear workspace etc), nothing helped.
- I could only open the project again after deleting the (hidden) project files. I also deleted .RProj.user (might have been enough to only delete .Rhistory ?)
- RStudio worked again, but when I ran a long pipe on a data frame with 300k rows, error `*** recursive gc invocation` occurred .

I then tried calling gc() first [as suggested elsewhere](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-fix-recursive-gc-invocation-followed-by-rstudio-crash/127607/2), but then

> Error in loadedNamespaces() : bad hash table contents

or

> gc Error: Invalid mset

**My solution**

I did not need to re-install R, but luckily enough had not double deleted my .RProj.user folder and put it back where it was before - this seemed to have fixed the problem *for now*.